# How to return top 2 values based on multiple column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, max, min

I  have columns like given --->

```
"id"| "name"| "hour8"| "hour9"| "hour10"| "hour11"| "hour12"|
 1     a        3.6      4.2      1.3       5.6       2.4
 2     b        0.2      7.6      2.3       4.0       0.5
```

I would like to extract the top 2 values from the hour of data from hour8,9,10,11,12 for the id, name.

I am a beginner, so any help or idea is appreciated.

I could get only one column with my query. But i need top 2 column values.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(maxhour) AS maxhour
FROM ##TestTabletb
UNPIVOT (maxhour FOR Val IN ( hour8, hour9, hour10,hour11, hour12 ) ) AS u
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

"i expect the output to be

```
"id"| "name"| "hour9"| "hour11"| 
 1     a         4.2     5.6
```

something like this.

Comment: Could you please show us your code and indicate where you are having trouble.

Comment: Also, what database are you using.

Comment: @HereGoes> have given the query that i tried.

Comment: Sorry not yet, I can't until tomorrow.  I still will need to know the database because depending on the database I may or may not be able to help.

Comment: its SSMS. sql server

Comment: ^^ You need to update your tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might give you what you need...

```
    SELECT r.id,
 y.val column1,
 r.maxhour1,
 z.val column2,
 r.maxhour2
 FROM (
SELECT  u.ID, 
MAX(u.maxhour) AS maxhour1, 
MAX(x.maxhour) as maxhour2
FROM ##TestTabletb 
UNPIVOT (maxhour FOR Val IN ( hour8, hour9, hour10,hour11, hour12 ) ) AS u,
     ##TestTabletb 
UNPIVOT (maxhour FOR Val IN ( hour8, hour9, hour10,hour11, hour12 ) ) AS x               
    WHERE u.id = x.id and u.maxhour > x.maxhour 
group by u.ID ) r,
##TestTabletb 
UNPIVOT (maxhour FOR Val IN ( hour8, hour9, hour10,hour11, hour12 ) ) AS y,
##TestTabletb 
UNPIVOT (maxhour FOR Val IN ( hour8, hour9, hour10,hour11, hour12 ) ) AS z
  WHERE r.id = y.id and r.maxhour1 = y.maxhour and
  r.id = z.id and r.maxhour2 = z.maxhour
order by r.id
```

Comment: This work like magic. But also, i want which hour it is, the top2? Is it possible?

Comment: I'll need to give it some thought.

Comment: I've made some changes, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you can try:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS "id", MIN(name) AS "name", MIN(hour9) AS "hour9", MAX(hour11) AS "hour11"
FROM TestTabletb
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

Comment: Thanks. I want the sort of max values to be column level.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ORDER BY.
ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2 DESC
Just specify your conditions and columns to be calculated.